Laravel Stack Overflow API Registration Issue
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm trying to register my Laravel application on Stack Overflow's API platform, but I'm encountering an issue. When I submit the registration form, I get an error message stating "OAuth Domain should not contain protocol or port."
I've tried removing the protocol (http) and port (8000) from the OAuth Domain field, but I'm still getting the same error.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I resolve it?
